# Android - HealthConnectClient.readRecords or aggregateGroupByPeriod takes forever

Tags: android, kotlin, healthconnect

Below codes takes forever to execute. Get it from official docs. **HealthConnect** is installed on the device.I believe there is an inner error that i cant see in logs of IDE. Code is **called** from `java` class.

What can cause this?

```
companion object {
    fun readStepsByTimeRange(
        healthConnectClient: HealthConnectClient,
        startTime: Instant,
        endTime: Instant
    ) : CompletableFuture<Long> = GlobalScope.future {
        innerReadStepsByTimeRange(healthConnectClient, startTime, endTime)
    }

    private suspend fun innerReadStepsByTimeRange (
        healthConnectClient: HealthConnectClient,
        startTime: Instant,
        endTime: Instant
    ) : Long {
        /*var totalStepsCount = 0L
        val response =
            healthConnectClient.readRecords(
                ReadRecordsRequest(
                    StepsRecord::class,
                    timeRangeFilter = TimeRangeFilter.between(startTime, endTime)
                )
            )
        for (stepRecord in response.records) {
            totalStepsCount += stepRecord.count;
        }
        return totalStepsCount*/
        val startTime = LocalDateTime.now().minusMonths(1)
        val endTime = LocalDateTime.now()

        try {

            val response =
                healthConnectClient.aggregateGroupByPeriod(
                    AggregateGroupByPeriodRequest(
                        metrics = setOf(StepsRecord.COUNT_TOTAL),
                        timeRangeFilter = TimeRangeFilter.between(startTime, endTime),
                        timeRangeSlicer = Period.ofDays(1)
                    )
                )

            return response[0].result[StepsRecord.COUNT_TOTAL]!!
        }catch (e: Exception) {
            return -1
        }
    }
}
```

**Java** caller code below

```
CompletableFuture<Long> totalStepsCountCF = StepReaderUtils.Companion.readStepsByTimeRange(
        healthConnectClient, startDate, endDate);
return totalStepsCountCF.get();
```

**build.gradle**

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.0'
implementation "androidx.health.connect:connect-client:1.0.0-alpha08"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8:1.6.4"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4"
```